# Bootstrap search box issues

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have the following piece of code in a .NET app that uses Bootstrap (3.2.0) and it is working quite well, though when gradually scaling the browser down step by step, the search box pops onto a second row, when I'd rather it scaled down until the mobile view kicks in.

has anyone had experience of this? Anyone come up with some nice solutions to overcome it?

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">                    
<div class="container">
<div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
    <!-- <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Connect</a> -->
</div>

<div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li id="ctl00_ctl09_homeli">
            <a href="/MRMConnectLatestApp/memberHomePage.aspx">
                <!-- <img id="ctl00_ctl09__imgHomeLink" title="Home" src="App_Themes/Default/Images/HomeIcon.png" alt="Home" style="height:28px;border-width:0px;Vertical-align:middle" /> -->
                <span id="ctl00_ctl09_Literal1">Home</span>
            </a>        
        </li>
        <li id="ctl00_ctl09_MakeBookingli"><a href="/MRMConnectLatestApp/mrmselectsite.aspx?disableSiteSelection=1">
            Make a Booking</a></li>
        <li id="ctl00_ctl09_ManageBookingsli"><a href="/MRMConnectLatestApp/mrmViewMyBookings.aspx?showOption=1">
            Manage Bookings</a></li>
        <li id="ctl00_ctl09_ManageSubscriptionsli"><a href="/MRMConnectLatestApp/MemberSubscriptions.aspx">
            Memberships</a></li>
        <li id="ctl00_ctl09_UnpaidSaleli"><a href="/MRMConnectLatestApp/ManageSales.aspx">
            Unpaid Sales</a></li>

    </ul>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right hidden-md hidden-sm hidden-lg">
        <li><a href="MemberManagement/EditMemberDetails.aspx">My Details</a></li>
        <li><a href="help.aspx">Help</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="search">
        <div class="input-group">
            <!-- <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" name="srch-term" id="srch-term"> -->
            <input name="ctl00$ctl09$SearchTextBox" type="text" id="ctl00_ctl09_SearchTextBox" class="SearchBox form-control">
            <div class="input-group-btn">
                <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>            
                <button class="btn btn-success" type="button">Advanced</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>      
</div>
```

http://www.bootply.com/sqwnkcDkjx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add the following class to your searchbox container:

```
<div class="input-group col-md-12">
```

Bootstrap will automatically size an input to the width of it's container. 
Use `'col-md(sm, lg)-*(1-12)'` to allow for more controlled resizing.